# relational algebra and sql query

Tags: sql, max, algebra, relational

given the folllowing sql query where i can find the name of the most expensive pizza

```
SELECT p.name
FROM PIZZA p
WHERE p.price=(
            SELECT MAX(p.price)
            FROM PIZZA p
           );
```

how would i make this into relational algebra. should this be fine

```
PROJECT p1.code - PROJECT p2.code(
                              SELECT p1.price >= p2.price
                              (P(p1,p) X P(p2,p)))
```

Comment: Is this school work? If so, please let us know.

Comment: @jarlh it was* school work. i am now revising my school work but i dont have the answer to that specific question above.